# fixing a ledger/tezbox device error problem

Tags: ledger, tezbox

I have a Ledger device, Ledger Live and the Tezbox App installed on my Mac. When I originally installed things, everything was working fine. Now things aren't working.

When I connect the Ledger to my Mac by opening Ledger Live and then opening the Tezbox App, I can see my funds just fine. But when I try to transfer funds from my Ledger `kt1` account in the Tezbox app to another `tz1` address I see the error `Operation Failed! Hardware device error`

I haven't changed anything. Not sure what the error is or how to fix it.

Has anyone else encountered this problem.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the precision, very useful ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely my error here.

The Tezos Wallet app needs to be open on the Ledger while trying to send funds.

This was causing my problem. After I opened the Wallet app on the Ledger while trying to send funds, things worked fine.